# How to automate bidirectional class objects?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm having two bidirectional classes. Is it necessary to always manage both ends myself? Eg: add both objects to each other, and also remove both references from each other before object deletion?

```
class Customer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    List<Employee> employees;   
}

class Employee {
    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;
}


Employee emp = new Employee();
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.getEmployees().add(emp);
emp.setCustomer(customer);
```

Same on deletion (first clear the reference, then delete the object).

Comment: Have you heard of Cascade operations before? you can set these in order to automate the delete based on the relationship.

Comment: Would I apply the Cascade.ALL only to the ManyToOne end then, right?

Comment: You can apply on both the ends also, but, depends on your need, if you want the other related data to be deleted, yes, you would do on both the ends, if you want only one side of the relation to mange the delete etc., you can do only one.